# Forecast R function : prediction interval is not symmetric across mean

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, prediction-interval

[image: forecast from BATS (0.399,{0,0},--)]

Using forecast function in Forecast package, I am trying to get mean and prediction interval for forecast period (h = 8). But I could not understand why prediction interval are not symmetric across mean value at each forecast period. below is code which I am running.

```
fit1 <- tbats(trainTS)
pred1 <- forecast(fit1,h = 8)
plot(pred1)
```

I have read github code for upper and lower prediction interval calculation in this [link](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/33eee3568632eed8d998434b014f054bf15ffd34/R/forecast2.R). as per relevant code below

```
lower <- upper <- matrix(NA,nrow=h,ncol=nconf)
s <- sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)
for(i in 1:nconf)
{
  if(n > 1)
    tfrac <- qt( 0.5 - level[i]/200, n-1)
  else
    tfrac <- -Inf
  w <- -tfrac * s*sqrt(1+1/n)
  lower[,i] <- f-w
  upper[,i] <- f+w
}
```

`w` is getting added and subtracted to mean (`f`) to get upper and lower value. But in my case, prediction interval being asymmetric implies that different value is getting added/subtracted to mean.

Any clue on what might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be explained in the help on the function.

If you don't specify whether to use Box-Cox transformation, it is tried and compared with leaving the series untransformed (i.e. with $\lambda=1$ ... though tbats calls this parameter $\omega$ in the help ---  I'm going to keep calling it $\lambda$ for now, that's what it's called in the tbats object)

Since you didn't specify, presumably some value of $\lambda<1$ was identified, which would then yield asymmetric prediction limits in the way we see after backtransformation at the end.

See the help for `tbats` and `forecast.bats`.

Comment: I didn't notice that a transforrnation had been selected .. my bad . Omission of possible empirically identifiable gaussian violations i.e. pulses/level shifts/seasonal pulses/local time trends unfortunately leads to difficult to explain "data tortures" such as .399

Comment: I think that's actually the damping parameter; the Box-Cox parameter doesn't seem to be shown on the plot.